# Javascript: Should I define it as array key or as object property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Which of the two approaches would you advise?

```
let x1 = 
{
  "type1": [{"data":"data1"}, {"data":"data2"}], 
  "type2": [{"data":"data3"}, {"data":"data4"}], 
}

let x2 =
[
  {"data": "data1", "type": "type1"},
  {"data": "data2", "type": "type1"},
  {"data": "data3", "type": "type2"},
  {"data": "data4", "type": "type2"},
] 

let type = "type1";
```

I guess .forEach or .map can work for both x1 and x2, such as below.

Case of x1:

```
x1[type].forEach(obj => {...})
```

Case of x2:

```
x2.filter(x2obj => x2obj.type === type).forEach(obj => {...})
```

Thanks!

Update:  `data` can be a question/answer object as in a discussion forum and `type` can be tags for example

Comment: depends on how you use the data overall

Comment: x2 is easy for me, searching and filtering seem to be more straightforward.

Comment: @JaromandaX can you please elaborate? I will greatly appreciate your discussing the scenarios. Thanks!

Comment: I can not foresee how **you** need to use your data, there is not much to discuss anyway ... the data is the data

Comment: It seems obvious to me that searching for data will be much more efficient using the `x1[type].forEach`, but if the rest of your code is easier to maintain by doing x2, then go for it. What will the data represent?

Comment: Does the app/page that uses the data often need to process by type, as compared to processing by something else? If using the second structure you could cache the results of `.filter()` operations to help with performance if needed.

Comment: @JaromandaX data can be a question/answer object as in a forum like this and type can be tags. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated!

Comment: About x1[type].forEach(), you get an exception if x1[type] is something wrong (null, undefined). So I prefer x2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how you'll mostly access the data. There's nothing stopping you storing a reference to the objects in x2 in a format similar to x1:

```
let x2 =
[
  {"data": "data1", "type": "type1"},
  {"data": "data2", "type": "type1"},
  {"data": "data3", "type": "type2"},
  {"data": "data4", "type": "type2"},
] 
let  x1 = {};
for(let i = 0; i < x2.length; i++){
     let type = x2[i].type;
     if(!x1.hasOwnProperty(type)){
         x1[type] = [];
     }              
     x1[type].push(x2[i]);
}
```

x2 it's easier to iterate over every element and perform an operation(ie as I did above iterating and transforming it). It'd be easier to sort and filter elements regardless of type.

x1 is easier if accessing the data by type ie if you wanted to say output items grouped by type.

Think about how the data will likely be used. How you'll access it should help you decide on a structure for it. How will the data be grouped in your view? Is it categorized by type all the time? If not then probably x2 if it is then probably x1.